# For each matching value, fill in the NA's of the other row with the corresponding data

Tags: r, join, tidyverse, tidy

Code to accompany example:

df1:

```
structure(list(point = structure(1:2, levels = c("1522", "2648"
), class = "factor"), x = c(-11.925, -33.454), y = c(-25.863, 
-23.163), z = c(229.018, 222.865), sr_bipol = c(NA_real_, NA_real_
), group = c("original", "original"), region = c("mri_healthy", 
"mri_healthy")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

df2:

```
structure(list(point = structure(1:2, levels = c("1522", "2648"
), class = "factor"), x = c(-10.9564, -33.1855999999999), y = c(-24.5931999999998, 
-25.8159999999998), z = c(229.196999999999, 223.619999999999), 
    sr_bipol = c(2.34, 2.109), group = c("sr_bipol", "sr_bipol"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

A minimal reproducible example: We have df1 and df2 and want the product dataframe. We only need the "region" to match and everything else to stay untouched.

[image]

What I've tried:

```
df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = "point)
```

What I get instead:

[image]

Comment: See `dplyr::rows_patch`. I don't like downloading strange data and you haven't showed any code so I don't really know what's going on, but something like `rows_patch(df1, df2, by = "point")` seems like what you want.

Comment: If you can share a small reproducible example that fits in the question--2 or 3 rows of data should be plenty to illustrate the problem--I'd be happy to look more.

Comment: @GregorThomas Usually links are images, so I left that particular comment, I shouldn't need to look at external links. A post must be self-contained, so those links are inappropriate whatever they link to.

Comment: A post must be self-contained & the text needs to be in the post not at a link. [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se] Also debug questions require a [mre].

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: @GregorThomas, I hope this fix is adequate

Comment: Well, I initially told philipxy to remove his links warning against posting data as images because you hadn't done that, but now you have. Please don't post data as images--we can't test code on picture. Use `dput()` to make copy/pasteable data objects, e.g., `dput(df1[1:3, ])` for the first 3 rows. That way you don't add to the work of anyone answering your question to type out the data as Jared did.

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas, I did dput just two rows of data per file. I think the dput output is very long because it defines all the levels of the "factors" in it, otherwise it's as short of a dataset as I can make it. 4 rows total.

Comment: Ah, you can fix that by dropping unused levels, `dput(droplevels(df1[1:3, ]))`. (I used to recommend this frequently, but since the default changed from factors to strings a few years ago it's not so commonly needed).

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks for all the back and forth, I've updated the data!

Comment: So, in your example there is only one value for `region` in `df2`, so it seems like we could just stick the data together and fill in the missing region values: `bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% fill(region, .direction = "downup")`. Am I missing something? Does the region need to be filled based on group? Where the groups are defined by, maybe, the `point` values? Or something else?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) PS hi @GregorThomas

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've understood the problem correctly, but perhaps this approach would work for you:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(vctrs)

df1 <- data.frame(point = c(1522, 2648),
                  x = c(10, 30),
                  y = c(24, 25),
                  z = c(229, 29),
                  sr_bipol = c(2, 2.1),
                  group = c("sr_bipol", "sr_bipol"))

df2 <- data.frame(point = c(1522, 2648),
                  x = c(-10, -30),
                  y = c(24, 25),
                  z = c(229, 222),
                  sr_bipol = c(NA, NA),
                  group = c("original", "original"),
                  region = c("mri_healthy", "mri_healthy"))
df1
#>   point  x  y   z sr_bipol    group
#> 1  1522 10 24 229      2.0 sr_bipol
#> 2  2648 30 25  29      2.1 sr_bipol
df2
#>   point   x  y   z sr_bipol    group      region
#> 1  1522 -10 24 229       NA original mri_healthy
#> 2  2648 -30 25 222       NA original mri_healthy

df1 %>%
  bind_rows(df2) %>%
  mutate(region = vec_fill_missing(region, direction = "downup")) %>%
  arrange(point)
#>   point   x  y   z sr_bipol    group      region
#> 1  1522  10 24 229      2.0 sr_bipol mri_healthy
#> 2  1522 -10 24 229       NA original mri_healthy
#> 3  2648  30 25  29      2.1 sr_bipol mri_healthy
#> 4  2648 -30 25 222       NA original mri_healthy
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>